# unmasking ListenAddress :: in sshd_config

Tags: networking, ssh, sshd

what will  happen if unmasking ListenAddress :: in sshd_config and restarting sshd service. Will I block myself out forever? Seems like I have done it.

Comment: If you had the IPv6 address for your server you can connect fine to it.  Sounds like you might be using Ubuntu 22.04 or older if my tests that I ran in the comments below are correct then.

Answer (score 2):

`ListenAddress` tells the SSH daemon what IP to listen to. If you have configured SSH to not listen on the IP that you are connecting to it on, then yes, you have locked yourself out. You need to fix the config from a console or physically on the server.

By default both of these lines are commented out:

```
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
```

Because by default, it listens to all addresses, both ipv4 and ipv6. If you uncomment the second line and restart sshd, that probably means that the SSH daemon is now only listening to all ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Is this still the case in more recent versions, where [SSHd now uses socket-based activation](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189) ?

Comment: @steeldriver Apparently it is still the case here in 22.04.  I did a test on it and this was the port it returned:  `tcp6  0  0 :::22   :::*    LISTEN 13769/sshd: /usr/sb` and nothing else.  I'll have to spin up my 23.10 and test it there as well.

Comment: @steeldriver In 23.10 it doesn't make a difference.  The line commented or uncommented and the service restarted I was still able to ssh to it without an issue.

Comment: @Terrance thanks for confirming

Comment: @Terrance On 23.10, it is recommended to edit `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/addresses.conf` instead

Comment: @DanielT Understandable, but that was just a test here for the answer.  OP seems to be using an older version where this actually matters.

Comment: @steeldriver I don't see why socket-based activation would be relevant to this at all and I think you both misunderstand its purpose. As your link states, "sshd will not be started until an incoming connection request is received", so systemd has one reality of what an "incoming connection" trigger can be, but sshd still has its own config. Just because systemd believes that an incoming connection is a relevant trigger for starting sshd does not mean that sshd will be overriden to allow it, whatever you put in sshd_config will have the last word, as it should be.

Comment: @pzkpfw I don't see how sshd_config is relevant with socket activation. Systemd listens and accepts connections, and gives connected sockets to sshd. sshd is no longer listening, so it doesn't matter what its listen config is set to. I can even restart sshd and there wouldn't be a millisecond systemd stops listening

Comment: You're right, I realized after I posted that since systemd is hijacking the port then sshd probably has no idea what the connection is coming from to begin with, so any listen- or port-logic in sshd is moot. Another completely insane design choice in a line of many by Canonical in my opinion, and this is the first I hear of it.

Comment: @pzkpfw You are on the right track.  When I ran my tests yesterday on the Ubuntu 22.04 install I have, I was not able to ssh back to my system when I copied exactly what OP did here.  I don't think it was hijacked at all as it wasn't listening on IPv4.   When I couldn't connect it was because I didn't have IPv6 enabled on my system to return it.  I will spin up a VM tonight that has IPv6 enabled on it to make sure that I can connect to is via IPv6 and not IPv4.

Comment: Your answer here is correct.  If OP has the IPv6 address they probably can connect fine.  Since OP does state that "Seems like I have done it." they have locked themselves out of their ability to ssh to their server via IPv4.  I can only duplicate OPs issue on my 22.04 ssh server.  If I uncomment the same line on my 23.10 ssh server, run the `systemctl restart ssh.service` I can still connect just fine over IPv4 and IPv6 just fine as 23.10 doesn't use the `sshd_config` file like 22.04 does.

Comment: Yes, it only applies to Ubuntu versions after 22.04. All versions after 22.04 have a “hijacked” ssh port by default which makes ListenAddress useless.